# Как удалить из вложенного объекта ключ:значение средствами lodash?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Имеется объект с вложенной структурой.
Добавить элемент в объект просто, а вот удалить не получается.
Подскажите как правильно удалить вложенный элемент ключ:значение.

Код и структура объекта:

```
const _ = require ( 'lodash' )    

.
.
.    

let obj_a = { }
let obj_b = { }
let objID, receivedKey, receivedValue = null

socketio.use ( function ( socket, next ) {

    objID         = socket.handshake.query.objid
    receivedKey   = socket.handshake.query.rkey
    receivedValue = socket.handshake.query.rvalue

    if ( objID && receivedKey && receivedValue ) {

        // проверяем на наличие нужного объекта, добавляем пустой
        if ( obj_a[ objID ] === undefined ) { obj_a[ objID ] = obj_b }
        // добавляем данные в объект
        obj_a[ objID ][ receivedKey ] = receivedValue

        return next( )
    }

    next ( new Error ( 'Authentication error' ) )
}

socketio.sockets.on ( 'connection', ( socket ) => {

.
.
.

    socket.on ( 'disconnect', () => {

        // тут пытаюсь удалить разными способами... безуспешно
        // -----------------------------------------------------------
        // _.remove( obj_a[ objID ], ( u ) => u === receivedKey )
        // delete obj_a[ objID ][ receivedKey ]
        // _.pull( obj_a[ objID ] , { receivedKey: receivedValue } )

        console.log( JSON.stringify(  obj_a[ objID ] ) )
    } )
```

Comment: А можно узнать структуру объекта? Какой вложенности?

Comment: https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от вложенности объекта и разрешено ли мутация объекта.

Если разрешено можно использовать  [`unset`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#unset)

```
const obj = {
  a: {
    name: "some"
  },
  b: {
    g: {
      find: true
    }
  },
  id: "88"
}

unset(obj, "b.g.find");

console.log(obj.b.g.find); // undefined
```

Если не разрешено мутация то можно использовать [`omit`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#omit)

```
const obj = {
  a: {
    name: "some"
  },
  b: {
    g: {
      find: true
    }
  },
  id: "88"
}

const a = omit(obj, "b.g.find"); // omit возвращает новый объект

console.log(a.b.g.find); //undefined
```

*Удаляя ключ объекта вы также удаляете его значение.*